# OpenSSL randomly fails to verify the certificate chain of a URL on the 443 port can verify all instance ports

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I'm hoping someone can help me because I am at a loss. My team has been suffering from issues of missing intermediate certificates in our services. I was tasked with writing a script that would continually test all our high-traffic service URLs one by one to verify that the certificate chain was complete. I wrote a C# program that ran OpenSSL and parsed the output.
Here's the OpenSSL command I ran on each url:

`"openssl.exe s_client -showcerts -servername " + uri + " -verify_hostname " + uri + " -connect " + uri +":" + port`

Or

`openssl.exe s_client -showcerts -servername www.euro-example-01.com -verify_hostname www.euro-example-01.com -connect www.euro-example-01.com:443`

Port is by default 443 and used 99% of the time.
If OpenSSL ever returned `“Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)”`, I'd know that an intermediate certificate was missing, and an alert would be fired. In addition, OpenSSL outputs the chain for me to verify this. This worked when testing against sites like incomplete-chain.badssl.com.

It is now running continually in the cloud and will throw alerts occasionally. However, many times our Service Engineer will check each server of the failing URL using the instance port and we will find **0 cases where it is failing**. We use round-robin load balancing, so shouldn't we expect at least one of these individual servers to be what causes the 443 to fail? The OpenSSL logs from the :443 failure case show only one certificate in the chain and sites like SSLLabs also confirmed a missing intermediate.

If our engineer rebooted the offending endpoint(s), then the full chain would be found and the alerts for missing intermediates go away.

Perhaps the weirdest part is that I set up a separate script to test just 4 URLs instead of all ~160 different URLs. Yesterday in a 30-minute timespan, `euro-example-01.com:443` was tested 12 times and failed 6 of those times on the original script. In that same 30 minutes on the new, smaller test size script `euro-example-01.com:443` was tested 12 times and passed all 12 times. It could be that the two scripts just hit different servers, but it seems suspicious to me.

As I said, we're at a loss as to why this is happening. I've had our Service Engineer check the load balancer and they say it's working fine. We haven't located any pattern of what sparks the tests to start failing. Do any of you have an idea as to why this is happening? Alternatively, is there a way to know what instance port is being hit when we test using :443? We may need to change to testing on instance ports instead of :443, but our instance counts change regularly and there's a high number of them.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

**tl;dr**: The 443 port on our URL will not return an intermediate certificate, but when we check the individual servers for said URL, an intermediate cert is always found.

Comment: All of your failures are at a load balancer? What is the nature of this load balancer?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing similar issue where one of the pods suddenly starts saying that signature verification failed. The other pods are working fine, and md5sum of certs in all pods match. Can't think of any explanation except in-memory copy of certs would have been getting corrupted. Don't know what to look for...